# Import Porkbun TLS cert into AWS ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tls1.2, aws-acm

Was not sure how to import my TLS certificates into AWS Certificate Manager.

The files you get from the download

- domain.cert.pem
- intermediate.cert.pem
- private.key.pem
- public.key.pem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private.key.pem` -> Certificate private key

`intermediate.cert.pem` -> Certificate chain

In `domain.cert.pem` get the first certificate block -> Certificate body